# JS. Добавить 1 час к текущему времени

Tags: javascript, дата

```js
const currentTime = new Date();
const expirationTime = new Date(
  currentTime.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000
);
const expirationIsoString = expirationTime.toISOString();
console.log(expirationTime, expirationIsoString);
```

Не могу понять, почему выводит на час назад, а не на час вперед:

> ```
> expirationTime: Thu Apr 06 2023 14:05:31 GMT+0200 (Центральная Европа, летнее время)
> expirationIsoString: 2023-04-06T12:05:31.898Z
> ```

Почему `expirationIsoString` не 14:05?

Comment: А почему должно быть 14:05? ISO показывается в GMT (собственно Z в конце указывает на это)

Comment: 14:05:31 GMT+0200 и есть  12:05:31.898Z

Comment: Понятно, ошибка в понимании того, что сделал. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: зависит еще и от локальных настроек, похоже. У меня оба вывода одинаковы, но не равны моему местному времени

Answer (score 1):

Выводится центрально европейское время, то есть -2 часа от Вас, так как этот формат подразумевает `.toIsoString()`